# FastReport .NET RegisterData

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

There is a method in fastreport called `RegisterData` that creates initial datasource and bind data to it.
So, I found a report that is already working in project, but when I'm trying to do the same thing I don't see any datasources in it.

```
var data = GetData(parameters) as IEnumerable<Days>;
Report.RegisterData(data, "DaysBS", 4)
```

When I try to select data source from design mode I can't see any?
Who knows why?
In already excisting report all works fine and I can see all registered datasources

```
Report.RegisterData(data, "UnUsedPeriodsBS", 4);
var vacationUnUsedPeriodDatas = data.SelectMany(d => d.Periods).ToList();
Report.RegisterData(vacationUnUsedPeriodDatas, "PeriodDetailsBS", 4);
Report.RegisterData(vacationUnUsedPeriodDatas.SelectMany(s => s.PeriodDetails).ToList(), "DaysDetailsBS", 4);
```

**EDIT**
Tried to manually refer to `DaysBS` in report design mode and it's working, but I can't understand why I can't see any report data from design mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looks like that the previous man who had coded the working report, first added binding sources, to use them from the report design mode, then deleted them, no idea why...
I tried to do so, and `fastreport` somehow remembered those bindingsources and all works fine.

Thus, there are no binding sources on the report and you can register data from the code like `Report.RegisterData(IEnumerable data, "Name of datasource")` and it will work

Answer (score 5):

> but I can't understand why I can't see any report data from design mode

Try to set tables from your dataset enabled:

```
Report.GetDataSource("tableName").Enabled = true;
```

Comment: How to set all tables and relations from DataSet enabled in report - https://www.fast-report.com/en/faq/18/267/